# Overlaying NDVI Images on Google Maps in Android Application

Tags: android, google-earth-engine, satellite

I'm developing an agriculture Android application, and I'll use the feature of showing NDVI images and NDVI values to provide farmers with more information about their farms and plants.
I retrieve the NDVI image from an API, and I get it as follows:

[image]

The problem is, I want to show this image overlaid on Google Maps, not just the image. To clarify more as the following image:

[image]

I don't know the right way to do this as I tried too many solutions but with no success.

Comment: Did you already read [this](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/featureview_overview#google_maps_api)?